# with http2, does each incoming stream run in separate goroutine>

Tags: go

In http1.1, each new connection is served by new go routine. So in http2, we could have just one TCP connection opened towards server. So for each incoming message over http2, will there be just one goroutine or there is on goroutine per stream?

Comment: This is not the right site for this kind of question. You should try reaching out to the people who has written the lib or read their documentation.

Comment: I thought golang related discussions happen here

Comment: You can have a look at the [help] section or take the [tour] to get better aquanted with the kinds of questions that are suitable for SO.

Comment: This question is fine for the go tag. http2 is part of the core system (in x/net). It'd probably be fine even if it were some random thirdparty library. We answer questions on thirdparty libraries all the time (though they should generally be tagged to make it clear what library is in question).